# Does the Azure AD audit log API work for Azure US Government tenants?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-gov

I cannot retrieve any signIn data from our Azure US Gov tenant with the following Powershell:

```
$ClientID = "<my app id>"
$ClientSecret = "<app key>"
$loginURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.us"
$tenantdomain = "<my tenant name>"
$scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" 
$body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret;scope=$scope}
$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $loginURL/$tenantdomain/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body  
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns"
$headerParams = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headerParams -Uri $url
```

We have AAD P2 licenses and the application has the required permissions to read the audit log data.

The same code works against our commercial tenant (after modifying the `$loginURL` appropriately.

I know the API is still beta, but I was hoping someone can confirm if it should or should not work against a Gov tenant.

I do not receive any errors, I just receive no data:

```
Content : {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/signIns","value":[]}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll have this update documented publicly soon at our [Azure Government developer endpoint mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-developer-guide#endpoint-mapping), but can you try graph.microsoft.us as the Microsoft Graph endpoint?

Also, the sign-in activity API isn't currently available in Azure Government and we are working on a date for that. However, the audit API (beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits) should be returning data with the graph.microsoft.us endpoint.

Can you confirm that this works for you?

Thanks,
Bernie

Comment: Thank you for confirming the sign-in activity API is not currently available in Gov. I tested it with the .us endpoints anyway and got HTTP 500 errors, the beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits API did indeed return data as you suggested. Its very important to us to have access to this data (signIns) via the API for compliance reasons and look forward to its availability.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that and understand the importance. I'll be sure to loop back with you once the sign-in activity API is available.